# update the ranking in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have the follwoing mysql table called user

```
 user  email            count  ranking
 sss   sss@gmail.com    111     0
 ss    ss@ggmail.con    11      0
 s     s@gmai.com       1       0
```

I try to use follwing mysql qyery to update the ranking

```
    SET @r=0; UPDATE table user SET ranking= @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY count ASC;
```

but it give me errors, I don't know where I did wrong, any one could help me with that? thanks a lot!

errors:

```
       SQL query: 

 UPDATE TABLE user SET ranking = @r := ( @r +1 ) ORDER BY count ASC ;



  MySQL said:  

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to    your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table user SET ranking= @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY count ASC' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TABLE` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).  Enclose it in backquotes when using it as an identifier, but in this case, it is unnecessary and should be removed.

```
SET @r=0; UPDATE user SET ranking= @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY count ASC;
```

Note that 99% of the time, the error message will point exactly to the character or word in the query causing problems. Look to the first word after the `'` in the error to start narrowing your problem.

```
> for the right syntax to use near 'table
```

Comment: MySQL is not my forté but shouldn't he just *remove* it?

Comment: @Lieven My eyes are failing me this morning.

Comment: lol, OP was helped by your answer, in the end, that's what counts.